# regex in cypher Neo4j

Tags: regex, neo4j, cypher

I'd like to write a query to count the number of entity. The entity has a key for me to match.
It looks like 12345CHINA
My query is

```
match(n:Name) 
where n.key='/^[0-9]{1,10}CHINA$/' 
return count(n)
```

And it does not work, returns me 0 rows.

How to write a correct one? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You not put a tilde after the equal sign. The slashes are not required:

```
match(n:Name) 
    where n.key =~ '^[0-9]{1,10}CHINA$' 
return count(n)
```

[ http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#query-where-regex ]

Comment: Cypher always applies a regexp to the *entire* value. Therefore, `^` and `$` are redundant and can be omitted without changing the results.